# source file.sh is written on .bashrc buy it is not working when launching .bashrc

Tags: bash

I have this line in my bashrc.sh

```
alias var1="source $HOME/track/setpaths.sh
```

so I close the terminal and open again but why is that I need to type 
var1 
to make it work?

in setpaths.sh I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# source setpaths.sh

export OPEN_HOME="$HOME/OpenRAM/compiler"
echo $OPEN_HOME
export OPEN_TECH="$HOME/OpenRAM/technology"
echo $OPEN_TECH
export FREEPDK45="$HOME/design-kits/FreePDK45"
echo $FREEPDK45
```

So in order to solve it I have to type var1 again.

It is supposed to work within the .bashrc file because "source" is inside .bashrc.

I am not supposed to type var1 again, when I type var1 on the export variables appear on the command line.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about `bashrc.sh` or `.bashrc`? What do you expect `alias var1="source $HOME/track/setpaths.sh` to do (that's a syntax error, by the way)?

Comment: Why `var1="source $HOME/track/setpaths.sh"`?? Just `source $HOME/track/setpaths.sh` in `.bashrc` to set the environment to include `OPEN_HOME`, etc.. (you can also simply use the `'.'`, e.g. `. $HOME/track/setpaths.sh`) `source` is an alias for `'.'` which is what sources the file. You should also check that `setpaths.sh` exists and is readable, e.g. `[ -r "$HOME/track/setpaths.sh" ] && . $HOME/track/setpaths.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the alias after defining it:

```
alias var1="source $HOME/track/setpaths.sh"
var1
```

Answer (score 0):

The setpaths.sh is readable I create that one.

In the setpaths.sh I wrote tree vars that need to be set eg.
export VAR_HOME="$HOME/data/compiler"
...
...

So that works I can launch it and work instead of typing variable by variable.

Then I open my .bashrc and write in the end this line:

alias openvars="source $HOME/data/setpaths.sh"

So by writing this line in my .bashrc I would expect just open a new terminal and avoid writing any variable.

But instead after opening a terminal I have to type
$openram so the variables are set and then I can lauch my program.

So how can I write this line on my .bashrc to avoid typing anything. I just one to open a new terminal and launch my program without setting any variable.

Is it possibly?

Thank you,